# What's the difference between [勝負]{しょうぶ} and [試合]{しあい}

Tags: word-choice, nuances, definitions, sports

I've seen both refered to as "match". Is there some secondary usage or perhaps a connotation or nuance that separates the two?

Comment: 試合 is a match/game while 勝負 is a duel/challenge/fight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I understand, `試合` appears to apply mostly (only?) to sports, but is also acceptable and considered correct for board games (chess, 将棋【しょうぎ】, 碁【ご】, etc. - see comments below).  `勝負` applies to these situations as well, but also to "fights"/"fighting" (actual, struggle for power, etc.), and to "the game" as in winning the game (the victory).  The characters for `勝負` literally mean "win lose", so it can also have that definition.

> - 真剣勝負をする　→　Play/Fight for real
> - 勝負の世界　→　The world where power rules
> - 勝負に出る　→　Make a decisive move
> - 勝負はこっちのものだ　→　The game is mine! (as in "I'm going to win!" or "The victory is mine!")
> - 勝負は時の運だ　→　Victory or defeat [Whether you win or not] is just luck.

Here is an image from the game [サムライ・スピリッツ]{Samurai Shodown} showing the pre-fight announcement ("Fight!").

[image]

And another picture from the same game when you win the round (`勝負あり` - "You win")

[image]

They also differ when used as `する` verbs.  `試合をする` simply means to "have/play/hold a game/match".  But `勝負をする` can take that meaning as well as "to fight/challenge".

> - 正々堂々勝負をしよう　→　Let's play fair [a fair game].
> - 実力で勝負する　→　Dictionary says "match one's skill (against a person)"

Comment: "Sports" shouldn't be taken too narrowly, you can use it with chess, see http://chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/detail/q1045697175
 As you pointed out, the important difference is that 試合 would not be used for a real struggle for power.試合:技の優劣を競い合うこと。　勝負:勝ち負け(を争うこと・戦い)

Comment: @blutorange:  You mean to say that `試合` can be used with chess?  Your link is broken.

Comment: This should work http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1045697175 There may be more appropriate terms, but everybody in that thread seems to agree that 試合 wouldn't be wrong, especially when used by non-professionals (of shougi).

Comment: So 試合 can only be used the traditional sense of a match (prepared in good time, official, etc.)
And 勝負 can be used to refer to anything where there's a winner and a loser? (A brawl, power struggle, a spontaneous game between two friends)?

Answer (score 2):

勝負(win and/or lose) = a match to make it clear who is a winner and who is a loser

試合(trial match) = a match with rules to train, to enjoy, or to enhance skills

Comment: Does this mean that 試合 can not be used for things that matter alot? Like the baseball finals?

Comment: Actually, we use 試合 for the baseball finals and the Olympic games.

They may matter a lot, but just "games" after all.

No one dies because of them.