# What does「勝負ありだ」mean?

Tags: translation, verbs, expressions

From what I see, it said "It's a match." Other place have said "what a battle", "it's a win," but there no consistency. Does anyone know?

Comment: I'm not voting to close, but could possibly be a duplicate of [What's the difference between 勝負 and 試合](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12368/78).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The character, 勝負, comes from `勝つ (win)` and `負ける (lose)` so it means `victory or defeat`.

So `勝負あり` describes the situation where we know who the winner is. 
The winner might say this when s/he feels confident that s/he is going to win.

`It's a win` and `It's a match` make sense but `What a battle` doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [link](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%8B%9D%E8%B2%A0%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A), it is something said when the winners/losers have been decided in a match.  That might be why the translator has taken liberties to use different translations.  The "what a battle" doesn't sound right to me, but that's just my opinion.

Answer (score -2):

> www.weblio.jp  --  勝負ありとは? 日本語表現辞典。 読み方： しょうぶあり
>   -- 勝負事について勝負が付いた、勝敗が決した、といった意味の表現。勝敗が決したことを宣言する台詞であることが多い。

It's similar to  「勝負あった」 in Sumo. -- means [ (the) match is over ]

> shinpankitei.pdf（388KB） - 日本相撲連盟
>
> www.nihonsumo-renmei.jp/about/pdf/shinpankitei.pdf
>
> . . .  示し、「勝負あった」 と発声するものとする。 第5条 一度「勝名乗り」を上げて判定を下した後は、異議又は疑義の申立てをすることが できない。ただし、審判員の協議結果と異なる選手に「勝名乗り」を上げた場合 その他明らかに主審の勘違い又は間違いと認め ...

Comment: 「日本語の引用を貼られても読めないし参考にならん！」 　　または　　「お前ググってコピペしてるだけだろｗ　この手抜きヤロー！」　 みたいな感じかな？